# Cannot create a contact in CRM 2011 Online using a plug-in

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Below is the code I am using to create a contact in CRM 2011 online. It's not throwing any error but it also not creating any contact. I have registered the plugin on Post-Operation create event of the e-mail entity. I don't know if I am missing something. Any help would be appreciate.

```cs
public class RegistrationPlugin : IPlugin
{
    private OrganizationServiceContext oContext;

    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
       serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);


        oContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);

        //service.EnableProxyTypes();

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
              context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            try
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (entity.LogicalName == "email")
                {
                    Guid _contactId;
                    var contact = new Contact()
                    {
                        FirstName = "Mary Kay",
                        LastName = "Andersen",
                        Address1_Line1 = "23 Market St.",
                        Address1_City = "Sammamish",
                        Address1_StateOrProvince = "MT",
                        Address1_PostalCode = "99999",
                        Telephone1 = "12345678",
                        EMailAddress1 = "marykay@contoso.com",
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                    };
                    _contactId = contact.Id;

                    oContext.AddObject(contact);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                throw new Exception(x.ToString() + "\n" + x.InnerException.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you're missing one statement which is:

```cs
oContext.AddObject(contact);
oContext.SaveChanges(); // <= Saves the changes
```

Answer (score 0):

It does solves the problem but it is now throwing another error:

Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples.RegistrationPlugin: System.Exception: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while processing this request. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated while overriding member: 'Microsoft.Crm.Services.Utility.DeviceRegistrationFailedException.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'. Security accessibility of the overriding method must match the security accessibility of the method being overriden.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.LoadKnownTypes(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.KnownProxyTypesProvider.RegisterAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AssemblyBasedKnownProxyTypesProvider.GetTypeForName(String name, Assembly proxyTypesAssembly)
   at..................

It seems to me a problem of rights. Can you suggest what I am missing now?

**UPDATE:** I solved the problem by adding OwnerID = new EntityReference("systemuser", context.UserId)

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I think you don't need to complete the ID field, because when you will create it, the CRM will send you the ID.

Don't know if it could help you, cause I don't create a contact but an incident. But I think the process is the same. So I let you look.

private Guid createCase(IOrganizationService CrmService, Entity email)

```
    {
        ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        tracingService.Trace("Just to tracing my plugin");
```

/* CREATE AN ENTITY: incident here, but could be contact, account, ... */

```
        Entity incident = new Entity("incident");
        incident["title"] = email.Attributes["subject"].ToString();
        incident["caseorigincode"] = new OptionSetValue(2);

        EntityCollection ec = email.Attributes["from"] as EntityCollection;
        Entity from = ec.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
        incident["customerid"] = (EntityReference)from.Attributes["partyid"];
```

/* END */

```
        tracingService.Trace("tracing 2.");
```

/* HERE YOU CREATE THE RECORD IN THE CRM */

```
        Guid caseid = CrmService.Create(incident);
```

/* END */

```
        tracingService.Trace("tracing 3. ID: "+ caseid.ToString());

        return caseid;
    }
```